# "404 not found" error after updating public_html

Tags: php, file-upload, http-status-code-404, public-html

i'm quite of a rookie at programming yet, and i have made a webpage a couple of months ago. Now i had to add some more functions and changes, and uploaded them to the "public_html" folder as it's needed, but after uploading (and yes, file manager Shows the new files and Modified ones properly) when i try accessing them from the web, they don't exist. New files go 404, and existing files i have overwritten don't show latest changes, it is, like if i didn't change Anything at all, it's like host still shows a previous "image" or ghost of the site before i updated it.

Is there any other folder i'd have to update my files than public_html? Also, checked on the "www" folder, and my files are there as well, but they won't show. Host is 000webhost.com

This might not be a 'programming' question itself, but it's about the latest phase, and i've been the whole night through it, so it's frustrating that i finally worked through and it won't show.

Thank you.

EDIT: [Uploaded page](http://www.agrovidabolivia.com/edit.php) , please try in to check if it's my PC cache or not, hope it is... if you get PHP error, exists, if 404, it doesn't

EDIT2: [Overwritten page](http://www.agrovidabolivia.com/productos.php) -> Modified/overwritten page, a magenta square should show below each of the products images.

Comment: If there is a www in public_html then it should be uploaded in www; it might be a cache issue, try to clear your browser cache.

Comment: Did your upload change the permissions of the file or directory to make it no longer visible? This is usually indicated by a permissions error but depending on your setup could be this.

Comment: @MikeM. i edited up with a link to one of the new pages i uploaded, please try getting in and tell me if seems to work or not. also i checked www directory (out of public_html, ther's no www inside) through file manager and files from public_html copied themselves on www, which is the usual thing, still not working

Comment: @ToothlessRebel , nope no changes made there, because i also did overwrite another file (productos.php, shown in EDIT2) and shows no changes itself despite being overwritten, that's why i think i'm in the wrong directory.

Comment: If you are on a linux-ish system try an ls -la on the command line from inside your public_html and see if your edit file has different permissions than your other files?

Comment: nope, permissions are right (644 all), and i think i have found the problem... the whole page was once hosted with another domain (www.agrovida-bo.com) now they changed it to (www.agrovidabolivia.com), but seems they only changed the domain and somehow Everything else (including upload files) point still to the First (and now useless) domain... so, if i tried to get into http://www.agrovida-bo.com/edit.php would possibly work, if the domain was still alive... damn what a mess...

Comment: lol, so they only changed the access domain, but everything in the cPANEL stil works with the former domain (which doesn't exist anymore), how can i change that?